# STM32 VBUS sensing with quick charge

Tags: stm32, battery-charging, usb-device

I'm developing a self-powered device based on STM32. The fast charging feature controlled by a chip using D+/D- USB pins. Once USB is connected, the chip performs "handshake" to know the capability of the charger, asks the maximum available voltage and sends a signal to inform MC that charging stuff is set up.

I suspect there will be a conflict when VBUS sensing is implemented in traditional way, i.e VBUS sensing pin (PB13 in my case) constantly connected to USB VBUS via resistor bridge.

Should I leave PB13 floating/pulled-up/down and set it programmatically after charging settings are done? If its not possible, maybe just control PB13 from another GPIO pin?

Thanks.

Comment: Please show the schematics. If USB does not go to MCU but to this charging chip, why would MCU need to sense VBUS?

Comment: D+/D- go to MC and QC chip. VBUS goes directly to QC chip  and MC PB13 pin via resistor bridge

Comment: Please draw a schematic. Which shows what is connected where and how. With exact hip names to find their exact data sheets. Is the QC chip even allowed to be on same bus with MCU.